# How to access files from host machine in flutter integration_test?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-integration-test

I have some basic questions which I could not find proper resources. My question is specific to flutter but I assume it could be framework agnostic.

When writing flutter integration_tests, we do:

1. Create test files in Android studio on `host system`
2. Run the tests using `flutter driver --driver=SOME_DRIVER --target=TEST/PATH` on terminal at `host system`
3. These tests are run inside an `emulator process` or mobile phone

I want to keep some zipped file with data on 'host machine' which can be used in android app when `integration_tests` are run. But I believe these process are separate threads/machines and not able to find zipped files while tests are still running. Is there a way to access these files dynamically?

I can see the logs are still written in `host machine` while tests are run on `android device/emulator` then there should be some channel which can read/write files to `host machine`.

Moreover I want to understand what are services and their host machines while integration_tests are run.

Comment: I could not figure out a simple way of transferring data from host to android device. I am transferring data using node server API. On setup fetching data.